# VBA - switch between X and Y ranges in Scatter chart

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use a for loop to switch between X and Y ranges for all Series in an active Scatter chart.
The exiting Series have value like this:

```
=SERIES("Name",Sheet1!$B$3:$B$23,Sheet1!$A$3:$A$23)
```

I want to change to:

```
=SERIES("Name",Sheet1!$A$3:$A$23,Sheet1!$B$3:$B$23)
```

switching between X and Y ranges.

## Please help to complete the function:

```
Sub SwitchXY()

    For i = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count

    'Please help here!

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why do you use a for next in this case, but if you simply want to change the formula of the chart. I believe you can work by this way:

```
Sub SwitchXY()
Dim formulaArray() As String

formulaArray = Split(ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Formula, ",")

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Formula = formulaArray(0) & "," & _
                                            formulaArray(2) & "," & _
                                            formulaArray(1) & "," & _
                                            formulaArray(3)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks anyway20! you saved my day! The reason I need to use for is because I am using Excel 2010, where the method FullSeriesCollection(i) is not available yet. I replaced it with SeriesCollection(1) with for loop and everything work well.